# IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code in a for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stringbuilder

I've researched the other answers here but none of them really fit my case. I've added a table to the database and now I am getting this error. Thing is, it worked on someone else's computer, but in mine, I'm getting the following error. p.s. My connections are fine (in case you wandered):

`IndexOutOfRangeException` was unhandled by user code

```
An exception of type `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot find table 0.
```

The offending code is the initializing of `int i = 0` in the for loop

Here is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string strSQLconnection = "Data Source=LOTUS;Initial Catalog=PMRS;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from PMRS.dbo.BOARDMEMBERS order by ORDERID";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConn;

        SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter();

        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            sa.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sa.Fill(ds);
            int rCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
            sqlConn.Close();
            sqlConn.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
            sqlConn.Dispose();
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() != "2")
            {
                sb.Append("<div class=\" col-md-6 \">");
                sb.Append("<img src=\"../images/board/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IMAGE"].ToString() + "\" /> ");
                sb.Append("<h3>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TITLE"].ToString() + "</h3> ");
                sb.Append("<h4>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FNAME"].ToString() + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MI"].ToString() + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LNAME"].ToString() + "</h4>");
                sb.Append("<p>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BIO"].ToString() + "</p> ");
                sb.Append("<p>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SUFFIX_PREFIX"].ToString() + "</p> ");
                sb.Append("</div>");
            }
        }
        Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

I am a front developer getting my hands wet again in server side programming so easy with me here. Explain it to a baby. lol Thanks

Comment: The problem is not initializing the i, it's that you don't have any tables in your datasource and you try to pick the first one (which does not exists), so it blows up.

Comment: Database is in SQL server. It has a table which I am referring to in the code and 10 populated rows. Database is exact same in both computers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the error because you're trying to access `ds.Tables[0]`, but `ds.Tables` doesn't have any elements. You have to check if `ds.Tables` is null and if `ds.Tables` has any elements before accessing `ds.Tables[0]` as below

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (ds.Tables != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) 
    {
        ....
    }
    Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
else
{
    // do something when ds.Tables is null or ds.Tables doesn't have any elements
}
```

Comment: This got rid of the error which is great! And it makes sense what you are saying too. Now I am getting a boatload of messages in the browser which are telling me the connection had a problem opening. Which is weird because I tested it, but you did answered my question. So, I'll repost for a different problem if Can't figure it out. Thanks ekad

Comment: @LOTUSMS that's exactly what I'm explaining below

Answer (score 1):

Rather than focusing on the result set, I'd rather look at your connection string and the exception wrapped in the `catch` block because it is obvious that the command/adapter is not returning anything. So, have a look at the connection string...

```
Data Source=LOTUS;Initial Catalog=PMRS;Integrated Security=True
```

and make sure that...

1. You have access to the SQL Server instance ...`LOTUS` with your Windows credentials
2. Make sure that the PMRS database exists
3. Make sure that the `BOARDMEMBERS` table exists in the above-mentioned database

and lastly, look at whatever going to the response here...

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex); //<------ check this out, there must be an exception bubbling up
        sqlConn.Close();
        sqlConn.Dispose();
    }
```

to check if there's an exception happening here...comment out everything after the `finally` block so that the exception (if any) can be sent to the response...because the unhandled exception is probably overriding the response with a "yellow screen" (if you haven't set a custom error page)

Comment: This is a very valid point Leo. I think this is why, although ekad fixed my error, I am getting some connection problems. The real SQLServer name is LOTUS/SQLEXPRESS, but when I do that it tells me that there is an escape and point to the /SQLEXPRESS portion. The web.config file does have the full connection string tho

Comment: I just added the whole name and I got this error Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: @LOTUSMS No, in that case, your instance name is LOTUS\\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: @LOTUSMS use a double forward-slash instead

Comment: @LOTUSMS ok, I'll send you my address so you can mail the beer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that when you ran the command to create the table it executed successfully (e.g. have you used a database query tool to look in the db and see that your table exists?)

Also, you should check what your query is returning and post it. Maybe it can't find any results?

Comment: Thank you anyway @Reapz but I needed more concise help. :)